# Stirling number of II type in Combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics

**How many less than 20 digits numbers have all 10 digits {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}?**

I suppose in solution appear Stirling numbers of II type, but how to use them?

Answer (score 1):

You want to partition the 19 digit positions into 10 nonempty sets labeled by the digits 0 to 9. For example, the number 1234567890123456789 corresponds to the partition [[10],[1, 11],[2,12],[3,13],[4,14],[5,15],[6,16],[7,17],[8,18],[9,19]].

Then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: To Nowak: If my answer is not clear enough for you to accept it, please let me know what else should I add. Thank you.